# jquery list iterator for all level

Tags: jquery

I'm on the verge of pulling my hair out..
I have this nested list

```
<ul class="css-treeview"><li code="tchdpt">Tech Dept<ul><li code="tchdptccsscntrl">Access Control</li><li code="tchdptffln">Offline<ul><li code="fflnntwrk">Network</li></ul></li><li code="tchdptnln">Online</li></ul></li></ul>
```

and the jQuery code

```
$(".css-treeview li:has(ul)").each(function(){
    var caption=$(this).html().substr(0,$(this).html().indexOf("<"));
    $(this).html($(this).html().substr($(this).html().indexOf("<")));
    console.log(caption);
    $(this).prepend("*"+caption);
});
```

All I'm trying to do is add a * before every list item that has a ul, but for the life of me I cant figure out why it seems to only do it on the first level (ie Tech Dept), but not on every level (ie Offline)

The thing is console.log has already shown that Offline should've gotten the * too.

I have a feeling that this is a very simple problem, but somehow I feel like I'm facing a blind spot. would anyone kindly point out where I make the mistake?

EDIT: I think I should make it more clear.. the reason I use a var caption is because I want to encapsulate the list item with a tag, to make it look like this

Tech Dept

- Access Control
- Offline

  - network
- Online

Comment: I think I answered this myself..

magically this works.. 
    $(".css-treeview li:has(ul)").each(function(){ var caption=$(this).html().substr(0,$(this).html().indexOf("<")); $(this).html($(this).children()); $(this).prepend(""+caption+""); });

I think the reason why it only parse the first level is like what Arun said, I shouldnt change html and treat it with text logic..

thanks everyone, at least I got this solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never do html manipulation using string manipulation logic.

It should be as simple as

```
$(".css-treeview li:has(ul)").prepend('*')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UutBd/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry i made something for you see this i thing that what you want

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.lists li:has(ul)').each(function(){
            $(this).prepend('*');
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is the script part and this is the html and css part

```
<style>
    .lists ul{margin-left:20px;font-size:16px}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="lists">
    <ul>
        <li>
                one
        </li>
        <li>
            two
            <ul>
                <li>
                        one of two
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                    one of two
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                two of two
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                                one of two
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            two of two
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    two of two
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

just copy and past and then see